# Radio button is not being displayed in a form

Tags: html, css, forms, radio-button

I use a external form to collect lead on my blog based on wordpress. When i use the form code in other pages, it works perfectly.

However, when i add it on my blog, radio button is not displayed. The code is the same, but i can't figure out why my blog code is hidding the radio button.

My blog is https://blog.boladetenisdelivery.com and the form is the first one in the right column (Avise-me dos posts novos).

The problem is in the question (in portuguese):

"Gostaria de receber promoções e novidades no seu email?*
Sim
Não"

Before Sim / Não (which means yes / no) should have radio buttons .

Anyone can help me?

Regards,
Eduardo

Answer (score 0):

It's a pure css issue. Add the following properties to the below class.

```
.bricks-form__label input[type="radio"] {
  margin: 0px 0px 4px -1.33em;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Zam.. thanks for your prompt answer. However, I can't add these properties to the class because its an external form. When i open de form out of my blog, it works: 
https://forms.rdstation.com.br/formulario-sidebar-blog-940e397219cfa80eac2a

is there any way to add a class on my blog CSS to force it to work?

Comment: You should be able to add the above css into your style.css file through the wordpress admin panel. Appearance > Editor > Select theme to edit from the drop down > Locate and double-click “Stylesheet (style.css)” under “Theme Files” under “Styles” section.

Comment: Yeah.. i did that before, but still doesn't work . https://prnt.sc/10js8mo

Comment: I don't see the new code reflecting in any of the style sheets. Are you sure you editing the right file under the right theme?